# Can I get vim-stlye (hjkl) navigation for GNU info?

Tags: vim, less, info

The layout of my netbook's keyboard means that using the arrow keys for navigation is slightly uncomfortable. Is there a way to make GNU Info pages use vim-style `hjkl` navigation? I know I can

```
info printf | less
```

...and use j and k to scroll up and down, which is good enough as I use info pages for reading so navigating to specific characters isn't vital; but it would be nice if I could do this within `info`, rather than resorting to a pipe.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question so I'll just post it as a comment. You can also use `info --subnodes -o - "$@" | less`. That way, you will be able to see all of the info about an item.

Comment: Note that the `info` standalone browser documentation is available at `info "info stand-alone"`. Where you can type `i` then `vi` or `key` and then `TAB` twice to see the matching index entries.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, info has support for pretty much any key binding scheme you like; see http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/Custom-Key-Bindings.html and note in particular the `--vi-keys` startup option for Info.

Comment: I think we have a winner, `alias info='info --vi-keys'` and *done*.

Answer (score 4):

The arrow keys are the least meaingful way to navigate info documents; as well, the hjkl keys are the least meaningful ways to navigate with vim-style keybindings.

Info uses emacs-style keybindings which aren't so bad once you figure them out. try `info info` to get started and then hit <kbd>h</kbd> to check out some of the keys. just the same, open a file with `less file` and hit <kbd>h</kbd> to see what it has to offer.

In vim itself, you aren't doing it right until you're using the many different keys for navigating through text-objects. `:help text-objects`.

Push comes to shove, [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=21) is a vim plugin to add an :Info command for viewing info pages with all the magic of vim keybindings. i would fully recommend learning how to just use `info` instead, as it was designed in a very particular fashion to be extremely efficiently navigable.

Comment: Thanks for this; the 'skip to next node' option is very interesting in particular.

Comment: That's all great, but some people don't want to learn the keybindings for multiple quite extensive editors ;)